# unity UI limitation for tutorial purpose

Tags: unity, gui, ui-design, ngui

i want to add a tutorial part to my game that i make by unity.i have some panels that for tutorial purpose i want to limit user to just click a button.most of games make a dark panel over all places except learning  UI.

i know there is lots of ways for making that but is there any standard way for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with Maskable UI. See Unity documents for Sprite Masking [here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html) or this tutorial [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1QktsHJwXCQ).

Also, you can use this paid Unity [Asset](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/gui/ui-advanced-mask-76663).